# django rest framework how to save mutiple phone number and email?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django framework, I have a model like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='organization_user')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(Hr, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='added_user')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

The Employee is not a Django auth user, and I need to save the employee with multiple emails and phone numbers.

I am using the SQLite database it's not having ArrayField as a model option.

Already tried like this :

```
 phon1='9400' (already in db)
 phon2='9411' (input number)
 phon = phon1 +','+phon2
 '9400,9411'
```

But here is the chance to create duplicate phone numbers.

Then how can I save the employee with multiple fields?

Comment: Why you are not using a `one-to-many` relationship? That is, having a `Phone` and `Email` tables that contain a `employee` field (_a foreign key to `Employee` table_).

Comment: @PedramParsian Can you show me an example as answer ?

Comment: @PedramParsian I thought that when make it as a foreign key, more difficult to code.

Comment: Maybe a little more code, but you will appreciate it soon when you want to ***use*** this stored data (_e.g. send an email or SMS_).

Comment: Unrelated (Pedram's answer is the only technically correct solution if you want to keep your schema properly normalized - actually you may even want a many2many relationship if the same phone number is used by more than one employee), but I kindly suggest you use a proper RDBMS instead of SQLite. SQLIte has it's use as a SQL-like lite-weight bitbucket for stand-alone native apps but is definitly not something you want to use for a production web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While technically you can have your phone numbers (and emails) as `"num1,num2,..."` and *prevent* duplicates, it's not generally a good idea to store them in this way.

The best-practice is something like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='organization_user')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(Hr, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='added_user')


class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```